# Show that linear operator T is bounded and calculate its norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Linear operator $ T: X \to Y $ is given as $ (Tf)(x) = xf(x)$. I have to show that it is  bounded and calculate its norm afterwards, when:

a) $X = Y = \mathbb{C}\left[0, 1 \right]$ with supremum norm,

b) $X = Y = L^p[0,1] $ for $1 \le p \le \infty$

I think I managed to prove that the operator is bounded for $X=Y=\mathbb{C}[0,1]$, but I'm having a hard time with calculating the norm. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint for a): the norm is $1$.

Comment: @Berci I managed to show that norm in a) is actually 1 by showing that it will be $\le 1$ and by putting $f(x) = 1$ we conclude that the norm is $1$. However I'm still struggling with b). I showed that the norm in b) will be $\le 1$, but I'm not sure how to show equality (supposing the second norm is also $1$).

Comment: I would try the characteristic functions of $[1-\frac1n,\,1]$.